# Bind AngularFire to a class

Tags: angular, typescript, angularfire

I have a class called Users.class and I want it to map or auto bind after firebase fetches the data. I am not sure how to search for the correct term. Been trying to find information.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import { Users } from '../Users';
import { UserService } from '../service/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edituser',
  templateUrl: './edituser.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edituser.component.scss']
})
export class EdituserComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route : ActivatedRoute, private userService : UserService) { }
  user : Users;
  key : string;
  ngOnInit() {

    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params =>{
      params.get('userKey');
    });

    this.userService.getUser(this.key).valueChanges().subscribe(data =>{
      user = data;
    })

  }

}
```

this would be the portion that I am having trouble

```
user : Users;
key : string;
  ngOnInit() {

    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params =>{
      params.get('userKey');
});
```

I have a Service of Users to fetch the data, but not sure how to pass into my Custom Class of Users. Or so say Bind it.

Comment: set the type of ``data`` to ``Users`` . That should help

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should have some sort of `user` object right here:
`user = data;`

If you are asking how you can assign that `data` object to the `user` property of your component class `EdituserComponent` - just change that line to:

`this.user = data;`

Otherwise, needs a bit more info, I think.
Is `UserService` your class, or is that firebase?
And what do you hope to accomplish with the passing in/binding?